# pushed value into std::vector but seems to be at wrong address

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, std

I've got this snippet of code, translating from an Assimp aiNode tree onto my own tree data structure. It's a quite simple recursive function traversing the tree, populating a structure with the node data, and calling itself for every child. The only difference is that instead of dynamically allocating each node, I push it into a vector, and use indices instead of pointers to connect them.

```
int AddNode( ModelDescriptor &LoadedModelDescriptor, const int ParentIndex, const aiNode *CurrentAssimpNode )
{
int NewIndex = (int) LoadedModelDescriptor.NodeTree.size();
LoadedModelDescriptor.NodeTree.push_back( MeshTreeNode() );
LoadedModelDescriptor.NodeTree[NewIndex].Name.assign( CurrentAssimpNode->mName.C_Str() );
LoadedModelDescriptor.NodeTree[NewIndex].ParentNode = ParentIndex;
LoadedModelDescriptor.NodeTree[NewIndex].DefaultTransformationMatrix = glm::transpose( glm::make_mat4( (float *) &CurrentAssimpNode->mTransformation ) );
LOG_DEBUG("processing node %u %s %u meshes %u children", NewIndex, LoadedModelDescriptor.NodeTree[NewIndex].Name.c_str(), CurrentAssimpNode->mNumMeshes, CurrentAssimpNode->mNumChildren );
for ( unsigned MeshIterator = 0; MeshIterator < CurrentAssimpNode->mNumMeshes; ++MeshIterator )
    {
    LoadedModelDescriptor.NodeTree[NewIndex].MeshIndices.push_back( CurrentAssimpNode->mMeshes[MeshIterator] );
    }

for ( unsigned ChildIterator = 0; ChildIterator < CurrentAssimpNode->mNumChildren; ++ChildIterator )
    {
    LoadedModelDescriptor.NodeTree[NewIndex].ChildNodes.push_back( AddNode( LoadedModelDescriptor, NewIndex, CurrentAssimpNode->mChildren[ChildIterator] ) );
    }
LOG_DEBUG("finished processing node %u %s %u meshes %u children", NewIndex, LoadedModelDescriptor.NodeTree[NewIndex].Name.c_str(), LoadedModelDescriptor.NodeTree[NewIndex].MeshIndices.size(), LoadedModelDescriptor.NodeTree[NewIndex].ChildNodes.size());
return NewIndex;
}
```

And here are the relevant structures used:

```
struct MeshTreeNode
{
std::string Name;
glm::mat4 DefaultTransformationMatrix;
std::vector <uint32_t> MeshIndices;
std::vector <int> ChildNodes;
int ParentNode;
};

struct ModelDescriptor
{
std::string Name;
std::vector <MeshTreeNode> NodeTree;
std::vector <MeshDescriptor> Meshes;
std::vector <LightDescriptor> Lights;
BoundingBox BBox;
};
```

Nothing to it, no hidden thingies. Works perfectly under windows, but got a nasty surprise last night while running it on Debian with GCC. NodeTree was fully populated after the call, but none of the nodes had a populated ChildNodes vector.
So basically, the first node was considered to have no children, and the node tree simply ended there.
After quite a bit of debugging, I noticed everything was running smoothly, the child nodes were being added, but for some reason, in the end, the tree had different contents. I figured the recursive calls were not behaving as expected, with regards to what was being loaded in memory at the time.
So I broke that little push_back call into two lines:

```
        int ChildNodeIndex = AddNode( LoadedModelDescriptor, NewIndex, CurrentAssimpNode->mChildren[ChildIterator] );
    LoadedModelDescriptor.NodeTree[NewIndex].ChildNodes.push_back( ChildNodeIndex );
```

Basically just temporarily storing the index in a variable before pushing it, but now it works. Apparently, that index is being pushed into some vector that is no longer valid by the time the push_back actually gets run. But from my understanding, it definitely should be, it should be the last thing in the call stack, and no matter how many times the vector had been reallocated internally because of the recursive calls, it should still be accurate during stack unwinding, since I assume it would only push std::vector's "this" onto the stack.

Can anybody enlighten me as to why this was happening? It doesn't feel right.

Comment: `int NewIndex = (int) LoadedModelDescriptor.NodeTree.size();` -- Maybe off-topic, but the `NewIndex` is unnecessary if you simply had `auto& lastItem = LoadedModelDescriptor.NodeTree.back();` after the `push_back()`, and then simply used `lastItem` throughout the rest of the function.

Comment: *but seems to be at wrong address* -- In anywhere else in your code, are you storing the address of the items you are adding to the vector?  If you are, then this is dangerous, as those addresses will be invalidated on resizing the vector beyond the current capacity.  If so, then that is why you are getting random, erratic behavior.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I can't. Imagine going for a node that has children ( as expected ). root node has children 1a, 2a, 3a. child 1a has one other child, 1b. main node will be at offset 0, child 1a will be at offset 1, then child 1b, will be at offset 2. 1b and 1c will be at offsets 3 and 4, but their parent node is not the latest, it's actually the first offset.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am not storing addresses, not even here. Only indices. I can only imagine that the resizing of this vector does something on the stack, because if I run this code as is on GCC, no node whatsoever has any children. Only if I apply the fix I mentioned above.

Comment: *Basically just temporarily storing the index in a variable before pushing it, but now it works.* -- Changing or adding lines of code that effectively do nothing is a clear indication of memory corruption going on in some other part of your program.  I suggest you put back the original code, and actually identify the bug and address it.